# Nested while loops. Inner loop does not satisfy condition

Tags: c, algorithm, flowchart

```
while(something){
 //execution 
  while(something){
  //execution
  while{
  //execution
 }
 //code stops.
```

In the above nested while loops, what if the second while-loop doesn't satisfy the condition?

Comment: You don't close any loop other than the third. If you post pseudo-code at least bother making it clear.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let's *brush up* the code, it's unclear what're included into what. In case the code has *nested loops*:

```
  while(condition1){
    Action1();    

    while(condition2) {
      Action2();

      while(condition3) {
        Action3();
      }
    }
  }
```

then if `condition2` returns `false` then `while(condition2)` *doesn't execute* and that's why *both* `Action2()` and `Action3()` don't execute. On the contrary for the code

```
  while(condition1){
    Action1();    

    while(condition2) {
      Action2();
    }

    while(condition3) {
      Action3();
    }
  }
```

if `condition2` returns `false` then `Action2()` doesn't execute only.

Answer (score 0):

If a `while` loop's condition is not satisfied, the body of the loop is not executed after the condition is evaluated and execution resumes after the end of the loop's body.

Answer (score 0):

It will loop in the outer while{}, without entering the inner while{} loops.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that these while loops are nested.

When first while loop condition satisfies, the execution will take place and if for second while loop the condition fails then it will not go inside the loop due to that third while loop can not process. because of that it will only execute the code for first while loop.